# How much can wordpress be customized? I want to create an Intranet portal but the plugins don't seem to be enough

Tags: wordpress

I tried to use Wordpress plugins including Buddypress to create an intranet portal but it does not include the features that i am looking for. Are there any good free plugins for such purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining all of the features you want your portal to have. Then search for plugins that offer some or all of them. You may need to use multiple plugins to achieve your goals. Since WordPress is written in PHP, you can create your own plugins and either modify existing templates or create your own templates from scratch. In short, the answer to your question: "How much can WordPress bu customized?", the answer is that it is fully customizable.